# Столкнулся с проблемой возврата данных в формах: login, register, restore

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

При попытке выполнить скрипт:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{

throw ValidationException::withMessages([
    $this->username() => [trans('Неверный логин или пароль, проверьте <br> введённые данные и    нажмите «Вход» ещё раз')],
]);
}
```

Получаю ответ сервера 500, вместо 422.

Есть точно такой же сайт на тестовом домене, там нет проблем, возвращает 422. Проблема именно с новым доменом.

Версии PHP одинаковые, домен везде где можно изменен, включая пути.

Добавлю, если распечатать при помощи dump работу функции выше, то в ответе видим правильные данные:

```
 ValidationException {#455 ▼
 +validator: Validator {#451 ▼
  #translator: Translator {#200 ▶}
  #container: Application {#2 ▶}
  #presenceVerifier: DatabasePresenceVerifier {#438 ▶}
#failedRules: []
#messages: MessageBag {#448 ▼
  #messages: array:1 [▼
    "email" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Неверный логин или пароль, проверьте <br> введённые данные и нажмите «Вход» ещё раз"
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
#data: []
#initialRules: []
#rules: []
#currentRule: null
#implicitAttributes: []
#distinctValues: []
#after: []
+customMessages: []
+fallbackMessages: []
+customAttributes: []
+customValues: []
+extensions: []
+replacers: []
#fileRules: array:9 [▶]
#implicitRules: array:10 [▶]
#dependentRules: array:18 [▶]
#sizeRules: array:8 [▶]
#numericRules: array:2 [▶]
}
+response: null
+status: 422
+errorBag: "default"
+redirectTo: null
#message: "The given data was invalid."
#code: 0
#file: "/home/v/vladish1/mydomain.ru/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate    
/Validation/ValidationException.php"
#line: 71
trace: {▶}
}
```

Однако при возврате функции через throw ответ сервера 500.